# Cookie ID is not changing

Tags: java, servlets, cookies

I have made a simple servlet that stores a random number as cookie id and when click on 'new identity' the cookie id should change, but the problem is that the id is not changing. Below is my code,

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class Cookies extends HttpServlet 
{
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
       response.setContentType("text/html");
       PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

       Cookie coki[]=request.getCookies();
       Cookie tokenCookie=null;
       if(coki!=null)
       {
           for(int i=0;i<coki.length;i++)
           {

               if(coki[i].getName().equals("token"))
               {
                   tokenCookie=coki[i];
                   break;
               }
           }
       }

       String resetParam=request.getParameter("resetParam");
       if(tokenCookie==null || (resetParam!=null && resetParam.equals("yes")))
       {
           Random rnd=new Random();
           long cookieid=rnd.nextLong();
           out.println("Welcome. A new token "+cookieid+" is now established");
           tokenCookie =new Cookie("token",Long.toString(cookieid));
           tokenCookie.setComment("Cookie named token to identity user");
           tokenCookie.setMaxAge(-1);
           tokenCookie.setPath("/ServletPractice/Cookies");
           response.addCookie(tokenCookie);
       }
       else
       {
           out.println("Welcome back. Your token id is "+tokenCookie.getValue()+"");
       }
       String requestURLSame=request.getRequestURL().toString();
       String requestURLNew=request.getRequestURL()+"?requestParam=yes";

       out.println("Click <a href="+requestURLSame+">here</a> to browse with same identity");
       out.println("Click <a href="+requestURLNew+">here</a> to browse with new identity");
       out.close();
    }  
}
```

When I run the above servlet in my chrome browser it displays,
If I click the link for "new identity" the the id displayed is not changed but the string changes from to that of "welcome" to "welcome back".

Kindly guide me through.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try using the debugger?

Comment: @RaunakAgarwal yeah but I did't found anything useful

Comment: You reset cookie when `resetParam` is `yes`, but your "reset" link sets `requestParam` to `yes`

Comment: @PawelVeselov hey thanks for your suggestion but I'm not quite following you, can you please elaborate.....

Comment: @YogiSachdev The request parameter you send to control the "identity" is different from the request parameter you expect to do it. `resetParam` and `requestParam` are literally different. Use string constants instead of literal expressions in your code to avoid such mistakes.

Comment: @PawelVeselov that was silly of me, thanks a lot.....